# How can I pipe the result of the wc command into an arithmetic expansion?

Tags: command-line, wc

I want to run `wc -l` and use the result in an arithmetic expansion. In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
wc -l (now somehow pipe/pass the result of this to) $((2 + result of wc command))
```

How can I do this?

#### Context

In my `~/Pictures` directory, I have multiple files named "`Screenshot from YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss.png`", as well as other files. 
I want to keep all files that are not Screenshots, and only a specified number of Screenshot pictures, based on how recent they were. I want to basically only keep the last 3 most recent Screenshots I have, and delete all the rest.

So here is what I have so far:

```
ls | grep "Screenshot *" | sort -r | wc -l
```

What I then wanted to do was to subtract 3 from `wc -l`, which would then allow me to use `tail` to list all the files that are not the first 3, and then just delete them.

Comment: `cat file.txt | wc -l | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'echo $(($1 + 2))' args`? More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3272724/4970442). If you tell us the problem, may be there is a more elegant solution ([XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))

Comment: @PabloBianchi this is what I was looking for. Can you explain the following: 1- what does bash -c do? 2- why did you include ticks around the echo command? 3- what is args?

Comment: @PabloBianchi also I added details on what I want to achieve above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you are asking ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3272724/4970442)):

```
cat FILE | wc -l | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'echo $(($1 + 2))' args
```

`bash -c 'commands'` run a new bash environment, where `$1` is an argument given by `xargs`. Use [`man the_commmand`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/) to access manual pages and learn more about each command and their options.

From [`man bash`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/bash.1.html#options):

> **SYNOPSIS**
> `xargs [options] [command [initial-arguments]]`
>
> **OPTIONS**
> `-c` If the `-c` option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument *command_string*. **If there are arguments after the *command_string*, the first argument is  assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters**.  The assignment to **$0** sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

```bash
$ bash -c 'echo $1' aaa bbb ccc
bbb
$ bash -c 'echo $0' aaa bbb ccc
aaa
$ echo $0
/bin/bash
```

So **in this case** you could avoid using the placeholder `args` (note you can use any word) just using $0 instead. Also, for just `wc -l` you can avoid the `-n 1`:

```
cat FILE | wc -l | xargs bash -c 'echo $(($0 + 2))'
```

For what you need might be more suitable to remove interactively (`-i`) files older than eg 20 days.

```
find ~/Pictures/ -type f -name "Screenshot*" -mtime +20 -exec rm -i {} +
```

To get the first 3 newest files with that name pattern is more simple:

```
ls -lt ~/Pictures/Screenshot* | head -n 3
```

Comment: could you just let me know what `args` is? I couldn't figure this one out

Answer (score 2):

Assuming FILE is a file that is located in the current directory:

```
echo $((`wc -l < FILE`+2))
```

`wc -l < FILE` returns the number of lines in FILE and `` echo $((`wc -l < FILE` +2)) `` returns the number of lines in FILE + 2.

Translating a string into a numerical expression is relatively straightforward using arithmetic expansion  of the form `$((EXPRESSION))` where `EXPRESSION` is an arithmetic expression.

Comment: Yes, but in a comment it is more tricky to show the syntax **and** display as code :)